# Error: Pagination(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: reactjs

So I created this pagination component.and I get the error `Error: Pagination(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.` in some parts of my app that I used whiles others works fine. I dont know what is going and how to fix it. This is my code. I tried other solutions but its still not working

```
const Pagination = ({ dataPerPage, totaldata, paginate }) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0)
  const pageNumbers = []

  const int = Math.ceil(totaldata / dataPerPage)
  if (int === 1) return

  for (let i = 1; i <= int; i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i)
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className="pagination">
   
        {pageNumbers.map(number => (
          <li key={number} className="page-item">
            <a
              onClick={() => {
                setCurrentPage(number)
                paginate(number)
              }}
              href="#"
              className="page-link"
            >
              {number}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}

       
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Pagination
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. It is hard to help without any code to examine.

Comment: yeah @DrewReese just added my code snippet

Comment: What do you think `if (int === 1) return` does?

Comment: Obviously, it checks for the result of the `Math` operation to 1 @DrewReese

Comment: I guess it isn't obvious to you that it returns `undefined` from the `Pagination` component.

Comment: okay. Do you have any suggesstions on how I can fix it please? @DrewReese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states `This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.` Your component is returning `undefined`.

```
if (int === 1) return // <-- returns undefined!
```

[Preventing a component from rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering)

> In rare cases you might want a component to hide itself even though it
> was rendered by another component. To do this return `null` instead of
> its render output.

You should return valid JSX. If you want a component to render nothing then the component should return `null`.

```
const Pagination = ({ dataPerPage, totaldata, paginate }) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const pageNumbers = [];

  const int = Math.ceil(totaldata / dataPerPage);
  if (int === 1) return null; // <-- return null to render nothing

  for (let i = 1; i <= int; i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className="pagination">
   
        {pageNumbers.map(number => (
          <li key={number} className="page-item">
            <a
              onClick={() => {
                setCurrentPage(number)
                paginate(number)
              }}
              href="#"
              className="page-link"
            >
              {number}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}

       
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```